# React / react-select module

Tags: reactjs

react-select (creditable), keeps giving me this error when I type anything:

```
Creatable.js?067d:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null
at compareOption (Creatable.js?067d:40)
at eval (Creatable.js?067d:51)
at Array.some (<anonymous>)
at isValidNewOption (Creatable.js?067d:50)
at Creatable.componentWillReceiveProps (Creatable.js?067d:133)
at callComponentWillReceiveProps (react-dom.development.js?cada:6389)
at updateClassInstance (react-dom.development.js?cada:6575)
at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js?cada:7848)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?cada:8225)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?cada:10224)
```

Comment: can you show me the a chunk of code that got error ? A suggestion would be, look at where you call `toLowerCase` method and check if that variable has a value

Comment: <CreatableSelect
              isClearable
              isRtl
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
              options={this.state.students}
            />
This is my code, am not using toLowerCase anywhere

Comment: can you provide me the link of module u install ? I have created a cra with react-select. It didn't have any errors

Comment: this module: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select

Answer (score 0):

options must be array of objects which each object must have the key called value.

```
<Select
  value={selectedOption}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  options={this.state.students}
/>
```

So your `students` value should be like this `[{value: "John Doe", name: "John Doe"}]`

Comment: my options are array of objects, when I type anything this error pops up on the console 
the options are working fine

Comment: does your object has the key called `value`?

Comment: yes it looks like this [{value: "Dalia" , label: "Dalia"}]

Comment: Do you provide the value to the Select?

Comment: I just figured that the problem only happens when I add this: defaultValue={{ label: 'Select Dept' }}